# Selenium Python - Selecting A Data Range

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, pycharm

[image]

I've attached a picture of the Calendar that I'm working with. 
I'm trying to select January, 1, 2018. However, when I run the xpath for any date other than October (the current month) it inputs an October date. So instead of January 1st it selects October, 1, 2018.

This is the code I'm currently using

```
#Open Table 
link2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/ tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[4]/a/img')
link2.click()

#Select Jan 1
link3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ds_calclass"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]')
link3.click()
```

I was just hoping to see if anyone else had this issue and how they got around it.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you try to send date to text input field instead of handling calendar widget? Also how do you want web-application to know that when you're clicking on 1st day of current month you actually mean 1st of January? Did you try to click `>` to change month?

Comment: I have, but it won't even let me manually type in the dates/ text. I could probably go through and click the left arrow key several times and try selecting January that way, but then will have to edit my code every month. Let me know what you think @Andersson

Comment: Also - I inspected January 1st and I figured that would be enough. When I inspect Jan 1 it shows me this html " <td class="ds_cell" oneclick(1,1,2018)">1</td>  I'll try using index instead of xpath and let you know if it works. @Andersson

Comment: No, I don't think you should hardcode the current month somewhere. The first option is to get index of current month (I guess all 12 monthes in HTML represented as list of 12 nodes...) and just by substracting the difference between month indexes you can get number of clicks you need to perform. Also you can get current month index on the fly with `import datetime; datetime.datetime.today().month`

Comment: Hi @Andersson I can't find a list of all 12 nodes. The HTML only seems to let me inspect each month individually. So it shows something like this:  <td class="ds_cell" onclick="ds_onclick(1,10,2018)">  Then  <td class="ds_cell" onclick="ds_onclick(2,10,2018)"> ...and so on. How would I approach selecting a date 6 months before today's current date? Right now I'm trying to use your import datetime method, but then how would I subtract 6 months? Would I do something along the lines of date.today() - relativedelta(months=6) after importing relativedelta? Any example code would help. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best strategy to use, but I figured out a way to go back a certain amount of months from the current date on this type of calendar.

```
#Go back 1 month by clicking on the left arrow key
c1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ds_calclass"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]')
c1.click()

#Go back 2 months
c2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ds_calclass"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]')
c2.click()

#Go back 3 months
c3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ds_calclass"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]')
c3.click()
#Select A Date
link3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
[@id="ds_calclass"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]')
link3.click()
```

This code allows you to go back 3 months from the 1st of the current month.

PS: You do this by finding the xpath of the left arrow and then the xpath of the the first of the 1st of a month.